# Out of Bound Error-Synchronising AVaudioPlayer current time with a variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, avaudioplayer, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a method that keeps updating the current Time of audioPlayer. In the same method i have a variable that gets incremented whenever the current audioPlayer time value gets equal to a time value stored in an array. I am using following code which works fine till the 5th value  but then the app crashed and give out of bound index Array Error. I am not sure what i am doing wrong. The whole idea is to highlight a row at index path stored in variable x and increment the highlighting after certain times passed stored in timeArray

A variable defined at interface

```
NSInteger x;
NSArray *timeArray;
```

check play back time method keeps updating every 0.1s by a NSTimer

```
- (void) checkPlaybackTime:(NSTimer *)thetimer {  //method gets called every 0.1s
    double time=audioPlayer.currentTime;
    double currentNumber = [((NSNumber*)[timeArray objectAtIndex:x]) doubleValue];//gives the values stored in Array
      if (time>0 && time<currentNumber){      //i used this method to increment x
        NSInteger*a =&x;
        [self highlightcell:a];
          }

      if (time>=currentNumber && time< 27.00){
        NSInteger*b =&x;
        [self highlightcell:b];
        x++;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose your `timeArray` contains 5 objects. The index of the last object in the array would then be `x = 4`. Now if you increment `x` to 5, then `-objectAtIndex:` would try to get a 6th object from the array, which cannot work due the array containing only 5 objects - this index is therefore `out of bounds` of the array (as only indexes 0..4 are valid values for `x`).

To avoid such situations, you should always check that your index is within the current bounds of the array before actually trying to access an array element:

```
double currentNumber = 0.;
if (x < [timeArray count]) {
    currentNumber = [[timeArray objectAtIndex:x] doubleValue];
}
```